# C# Code running fine in one project does not work in another

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, datagridview, ado.net

The following code (exactly the same) is running fine on another project.

```
 private void AddComboBoxCells()
        {
            DataGridViewComboBoxCell dgvcell;
            _query = "select ProductName from Product";
                com = new SqlCommand(_query, con);
                    for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
                    {
                        dgvcell = new DataGridViewComboBoxCell();
                        dataGridView1[1, i] = dgvcell;
                        myrdr = com.ExecuteReader();
                        while (myrdr.Read())
                        {
                            dgvcell.Items.Add(myrdr.GetValue(0));
                        }
                        myrdr.Close();
                    }

        }
```

On this project currently i am trying to run this same code but i am getting following error at runtime:

[image]

What i am doing is i am pulling records i.e. product names and populating it in the second column of the datagridviewcomboboxcell.

**EDIT**

```
 private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataRow dtr = tblOrders.NewRow();
        tblOrders.Rows.Add(dtr);
        DataGridViewComboBoxCell dgvcell;
        _query = "select * from Product";
        com = new SqlCommand(_query, con);
            dgvcell = new DataGridViewComboBoxCell();
            dataGridView1[1, dataGridView1 .Rows.Count -2 ] = dgvcell;
            myrdr = com.ExecuteReader();
            while (myrdr.Read())
            {
                dgvcell.Items.Add(myrdr[0]);
            }
            myrdr.Close();
    }
```

This Add button Code works hence the Data coming in is valid for sure. Please assist.

Comment: On what source code row does the error occur?

Comment: The last row - it populates the first row fine and keeps the previous value laptop correct, however in second row it changes Desktop to Fax

Comment: Second row in Table contains:
2 Desktop 2 3 6000

Comment: I can't see the error message!

Comment: Daniel Persson means "on which code line?" not on which data row.

Comment: Please post the text of the error message.  Some users are prevented from seeing screen shots (i. e. imgur.com is blocked).

Comment: If i debug the code it does not give the errors until the control goes out of AddComboBoxCells function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you may want to attach a handler to the DataError event of the DataGridView control to get access to more information about the error you are getting.

Second, the obvious things to check are the data context that you're using in the second project. It seems very likely that it is not a programming error necessarily but more like an issue that is related to the underlying data that you are querying and/or doing data binding against.

You may want to investigate the **type of data** and **the values** that are returned by your query: `select ProductName from Product`.

Look at `myrdr.getValue(0)` - rewrite the line `dgvcell.Items.Add(myrdr.GetValue(0));` like this:

```
object val = myrdr.GetValue(0);  
dgvcell.Items.Add(val);         // put a break-point here and check val
```

**EDIT**

To answer your question regarding how to handle the DataError event, all you need to do is simply attach a handler to the event member of your 'dataGridView1' object (if you don't know what events are, or how to attach handlers to events in C# then I suggest you do some reading about that online - there are tons of resources everywhere)

```
// you will want to add this code to attach the handler in your initialization code - maybe in the Load event handler
dataGridView1.DataError += new DataGridViewDataErrorEventHandler(DataGridView1);

// ....

// an then define this function somewhere in your class to handle the event
private void DataGridView1_DataError(object sender, DataGridViewDataErrorEventArgs anError)
{
     // this function will be called when an error occurs.
     //  you can then use the anError paramenter to get insight into the type and cause of the error
}
```

Comment: Everything is same. Even the types. Can you show an example, how to write a DataHandler?

Comment: Have you tried attaching the event handler as I suggested. If so, what happens when you run with the debugger (put a breakpoint inside the event handler).

Answer (score 2):

Do you have valid data in your second project? I'd *guess* that your call to `myrdr.GetValue(0)` is returning null (or some other bogus value) at some point?

Comment: Most likely it is returning `DBNull`, not `null`.